# How to disable "Slide for Calculator" on Zenbook UX435EG_UX435EG Touchpad?

Tags: windows-11, asus-laptop, zenbook

I use Asus Zenbook UX435EG_UX435 brand laptop. I am often disturbed by the features on the touchpad, namely:

1. Slide for brightness control
2. Slides for calculator
3. NumberPad (On/of numeric)

TouchPad Image:
[image]
For point 3, I can disable it [this way](https://www.carehart.org/blog/2020/12/20/how_to_disable_asus_numberpad).

But for points 1 and 2 I still haven't found a solution.
Every time I do my work using a laptop, I often accidentally touch the "slide for calculator" feature, when I activate that feature the calculator app automatically appears and it really disturbs my concentration at work. That's why I want to disable that feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every time I do my work using a laptop, I often accidentally touch the "slide for calculator" feature, when I activate that feature the calculator app automatically appears and it really disturbs my concentration at work. That's why I want to disable that feature.

Comment: I only just found this. It seems to me that the original question was pretty clear. So, were you ever able to figure this out? I've been trying to find an answer to the same problem, but without success so far.